# Can weak* convergence be upgraded to strong convergence in this situation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

$\newcommand{\mr}{\mathscr}$

## Definitions.

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\mr P(X)$ be the set of all the probability measures on $X$.
We say that a sequence $(\nu_n)$ in $\mr P(X)$ **converges to** $\nu\in \mr P(X)$ **in the weak* sense** if for all continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb R$, we have that
$$\int_Xf \ d\nu_n \to \int_X f\ d\nu$$

We say that a sequence $(\nu_n)$ in $\mr P(X)$ converges to $\nu$ **strongly** if for all Borel sets $A$ in $X$ we have
$$\nu_n(A)\to \nu(A)$$

## Question.

Suppose we are given a sequence $\mu_n$ in $\mr P(X)$.
Define the averages
$$\nu_n = \frac{\mu_1 +\cdots +\mu_n}{n}$$
for each $n\geq 1$.
Assume that the sequence $\nu_n$ converges to a probability measure $\nu$ in the weak* sense.

> **Question** Does it follow that $\nu_n$ actually converges to $\nu$ strongly?

In other words, do we get strong convergence from weak convergence in this special situation?

(*Please Ignore:* It is clear that for any Borel set $E$ we have $(\nu_n(E))$ is a Cauchy sequence. So it converges to something.)

(Thanks to @Davide Giraudo for pointing that the above was a hasty remark.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no: let $(m_i)$ be a sequence of probability measure which converges weakly to $\nu$ but not strongly. Let $(N_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of integers such that 
$$
N_1=1, N_{j+1}=2jN_j .
$$
For $n$ such that $N_k+1\leqslant n\leqslant N_{k+1}$, we define $\mu_n:=m_k$. In this way, $\mu_n\to \nu$ weakly. We have 
$$\nu_{N_{j+1}}=\frac 1{N_{j+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\sum_{n=N_k+1}^{N_{k+1}}\mu_n
=\frac 1{N_{j+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\left(N_{k+1}-N_k\right)m_k
=m_j-  \frac{N_j}{N_{j+1}} m_j+\frac 1{N_{j+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\left(N_{k+1}-N_k\right)m_k.
$$
For any Borel subset $E$ of $X$, 
$$\left\lvert -  \frac{N_j}{N_{j+1}} m_j(E)+\frac 1{N_{j+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\left(N_{k+1}-N_k\right)m_k(E)\right\rvert\leqslant 2\frac{N_j}{N_{j+1}}\leqslant j^{-1}$$
hence if $E$ is such that the sequence $\left(m_j(E)\right)_j$ does not converge to $\nu(E)$, the sequence $\left(\nu_{N_{j}}(E)\right)$ does not converge to $\nu(E)$.